# My add command isn't working

Tags: lua

```
function read_file(file)
local data = io.open(file, "r")
for char in data:lines() do
    local num1 = 0
    local num2 = 0
    --Print statement
    if char:sub(1, 6) == "print>" then
        print(char:sub(7))
    end
    --Setting numbers command
    if char:sub(1, 5) == "num1>" then
        num1 = char:sub(6)
    end
    if char:sub(1, 5) == "num2>" then
        num2 = char:sub(6)
    end
    --The add command
    if char:sub(1, 5) == "add()" then
        print(num1 + num2)
    end
end
data:close()
end

function run()
while true do
    print("Open a file")
    file = io.read()
    print("")
    print("Opening file: "..file)
    print("")
    read_file(file)
    print("")
    print("Successfully compiled\n")
end
    end

run()
```

My "Setting numbers command" isn't working, the variables num1 and num2 are set as 0 and they wont change so I have been stuck for about 30 mins thinking about how to fix it and I cant think of how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> variables num1 and num2 are set as 0 and they wont change

Because you reset them to 0 at the start of the loop.

Change this:

```
for char in data:lines() do
   local num1 = 0
   local num2 = 0
   ...
```

To this:

```
local num1 = 0
local num2 = 0
for char in data:lines() do
    ...
```

---

By the way, you can replace this:

```
local data = io.open(file, "r")
for char in data:lines() do
   ...
end
data:close()
```

With this, which does the same thing:

```
for lines in io.lines(file) do
   ...
end
```